# vertical progress bar flex

Tags: apache-flex, layout, progress-bar

Hi
I want to use the mx:ProgressBar of flex just in order to be able to show a filled bar according to a certain percentage(If there is a different control to use, please suggest).
Anyhow, I want to show the control flipped by 90 degrees.
I tried to use the rotation="90" but after the rotation you have to set the x coordinate in order to move it to the right and I want to avoid this.
Is there any other way except rotation="90" ?

Thanks,
Clint

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to rotate on the center you try the trick of using rotating animation:

```
  <mx:Rotate
    id="ID"
    angleFrom="0"
    angleTo="360"
    originX="0"
    originY="0"
  />
```

With rotation animation you can specify originX/originY so you can rotate it on its center. Call the rotate motion on component creationcomplete